# Are CLI commands available for Ubuntu Touch’s SMS, Phone and Camera service? If so, what are the commands and where are the man pages for them?

Tags: 14.10, ubuntu-touch, aquaris

I’m running Ubuntu Touch 14.10(r21) default OS for Aquarius e4.5 Ubuntu Edition. I want to be able to control some of the phone’s capabilities via ssh and CLI. I can ssh to the phone fine but I cant seem to find the commands for SMS messaging, phone calls, or the camera. I have tried to tail –f logs in /var/log to no avail.

Are CLI commands available for Ubuntu Touch’s  SMS, Phone and Camera service? If so, what are the commands and where are the man pages for them?

Answer (score 3):

You can send SMS by commandline doing:

```
/usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 <target phone number> "your Text" 0
```

I think

```
/ril_0
```

represents SIM-Card 1, whereas

```
/ril_1
```

represents SIM-Card 2 (if you have two installed). Or in other words, the SIM-Card which will be used to send out the sms.
I don't know if there are man-pages, i didn't look for it yet.

Maybe interesting concerning scripting and sending SMS:

Thread "battery 83% to 0% in 1 hour of not using the BQ" on Ubuntu-phone mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring the camera application to get streaming working (still haven't managed to find anyone who can explain me how to compile the whole camera chain).

It doesn't have CLI interface.

As I understand (may be wrong), camera works through some android/java driver that is plugged into Qt that is used by the application. There is no video4linux and gstreamer there.

Comment: If ubuntu touch's core apps dont have a CLI interface then I would say the development team has deviated from a very fundamental part of Linux in of itself.